# "SwiftSupport folder is empty" error when publishing to iTunes Connect using Appcelerator

Tags: ios, swift, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to publish an iOS app to iTunes Connect using Appcelerator (note: this app was created by another developer).

The app uploaded fine, but iTunes then sends the email with the following error message:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "XXXX". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty. Rebuild your
>   app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I'm quite new to Appcelerator, but I can't seem to find any relevant answers to this problem (although there a few answers relating to X-Code).

Comment: I don't use Appcelerator myself, so I'm not sure if that's the issue causing this folder to be empty. But using Xcode itself (I've used version 7 and 8) to archive, upload, and submit works very well. Have you tried that?

Comment: @dfd When you package an app using Appcelerator, the archive, upload and submit is done through XCode

Comment: Thanks. I decided to check it out, hoping to see if they had a product forum. I was surprised that their help page mentions SO prominently and the only other "help" was a Google search. Obviously the Xcode pieces work, as your submission was rejected. I wish you luck getting an answer to the issue. (If you do, I suggest posting the answer here as it'll help others who wish to go for help on their site.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to update XCode!

Answer (score 0):

You should choose "Save for iOS App Store Deployment" option at the time of exporting ipa file.[image]